# is there any function in sql which may return the result from first two alphabet or the first alphabet?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am working on oracle10g. I was curious to know that is there any SQL function which may give results from the starting alphabet of a string.

For example, if I have road-1, road-A, road-89 and I want to know total number of such road sets without using the sql `count()` function.

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with the `count()` function?

Comment: i was just curious to know some alternate approach

Comment: let me modify my question, i want to search a specific string among the all the entities of one column. So for example if i want to search by keyword "road" it should return all types of road

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For values that start with `road`:

```
SELECT YourColumn, COUNT(*) Total
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourColumn LIKE 'road%'
```

For values that contains `road` somewhere:

```
SELECT YourColumn, COUNT(*) Total
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourColumn LIKE '%road%'
```